# Override helper in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I'm trying override getBreadcrumbPath() in  Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data.

> In di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data">
    <plugin name="Helper" type="XXX\YYY\Plugin\Helper\Data" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

In plugin

```
public function aroundGetBreadcrumbPath(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $subject, callable $proceed)
{
echo "hi";exit;
}
```

But its not working

Answer (score 2):

1.Create file **di.xml** inside Vendor/Module/etc

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data">
    <plugin name="catalog-helper-data" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Data" />
</type>
```

2.Create file **Data.php** inside Vendor/Module/Plugin

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
class Data
{
public function aroundGetBreadcrumbPath(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        echo "hi";exit;  
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

An around plugin needs to always have a return value. The return value should be something like:

```
$result = $proceed(PARAMETERS FROM THE ORIGINAL FUNCTION);
```

You can look at the documentation [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html).

Not sure if there is more that you are missing.

Does your di.xml also start with the following?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
```